# Setting element height to clientHeight cause page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have this piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>      
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            document.getElementById("c").width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            document.getElementById("c").height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;">
    <canvas id="c" style="background-color: red;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why it generates canvas bigger than browser viewport, and makes scrollbar? And beside that it makes some white space below canvas. Why and how to solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default canvas display are set to `display: inline;` 
You just have to set your canvas display to `display: block;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script>      
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            document.getElementById("c").width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            document.getElementById("c").height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        })
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0;">
    <canvas id="c" style="background-color: red; display: block;"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```